# Output Image Using keras - how to specify shape for output layer. Input Image and Output Image Dimensions are(210,210,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am new to Keras. I am trying to feed a color inverted image into a neural network and then predict the real image. So that my x becomes the inverted image and y becomes the real image.
But I am not knowing how to get an output image with keras.

[image: This is what i wanna perform]

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense

real=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    img=load_img(f"resized 1/{i}.jpg",target_size=(210,200))
    img=img_to_array(img)
    real.append(img)

invs=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    img=load_img(f"resized 2/{i}i.jpg",target_size=(210,200))
    img=img_to_array(img)
    invs.append(img)

x=np.array(invs)
y=np.array(real)
x=x/255
y=y/255


model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,input_shape=x.shape[1:],activation='relu'))
```

**what should i do after this how should i specify the output layer....I'm stuck**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y,epochs=5,validation_split=0.1)
```

Thanks in advance....
I have referred this post but cant get anything - [Keras: feed images into CNN and get image output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210836/keras-feed-images-into-cnn-and-get-image-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a classification or regression problem. Thus, the type of neural network that you are using (Convolutional) is not suitable for this problem.

I think neural style transfer would be more appropriate. In this case Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) should be used.
You can read example about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

Comment: No, this is a regression problem, so CNNs can surely do it. CNNs also can do more than just classification and regression

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.Do you have any example or reference of how it can be done? This will be an interesting use case.

Comment: After doing research in GANs.This problem is suitable for Pix2Pix GAN.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-pix2pix-gan-models-from-scratch-with-keras/